# pgBouncer does not use all availeable CPUs

Tags: performance, cpu-usage, pgbouncer

I have a Server with multiple cores taht's suppose to run pgBouncer (1.7). 
It's working pretty well, but it occupies only one cpu. I get pretty high latency values when i doe a load test with pgbench, emulating several Clients. (27ms without pgbouncer and 62ms with pgbouncer).

how can i make pgbouncer use all available cpus?

Comment: a duplicate of: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149383/pgbouncer-does-not-use-all-available-cpus